# Compile asm file with c files using cmake

Tags: c, assembly, cmake, nasm

I need to compile a static library composed by c files and one asm file using CMake. In the lib dir I have a `CMakeLists.txt` similar to the following:

```
I have moved the 
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER nasm)

in an upper cmake list and modified de inner

enable_language(C ASM) 
 
include(sourcelist)
add_library(myLib ${sources} foo.asm)
 
set_property(   SOURCE ${sources}   APPEND   PROPERTY
  COMPILE_DEFINITIONS   "MYDEF1" ;"MYDEF2")
set_source_files_properties(${sources} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -fPIC)
 
set_property(
  foo.asm
  APPEND
  PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
  "QNXNTO")

set_source_files_properties(${sources_asm} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-f elf ")

target_include_directories(myLib PRIVATE ../}
```

where `${sources}` are my c files that are compiled correctly, but
when I try to compile the asm file I got

```
/usr/bin/nasm  -DQNXNTO -f elf  -o CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/foo.asm.o -c foo.asm 
nasm: error: unrecognised option `-c'


So I have the problem with -c option, it should be -s
```

How can I remove the unwanted "-c" ?

Comment: CMake checks asm compiler and adapt options for it when you call `enable_language(ASM)`. If you want to change the compiler, you need to set `CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER` **before** `enable_language` call.

Comment: done but still I have some problem

Comment: Please, add the **whole your code** into the question post in form of [mcve]. Also, please add output of CMake when it configures your project (when you run `cmake`): this output contains a description of the compiler, which is detected by CMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue:

1. in the outer cmake list set
   .....

   set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER /usr/bin/nasm)
   set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS asm)
   set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT elf)

.....

2. the inner one will be modified in the folowing way:

   enable_language(C ASM_NASM)

   include(sourcelist)
   add_library(myLib ${sources} foo.asm)

   set_property(   SOURCE ${sources}   APPEND   PROPERTY
   COMPILE_DEFINITIONS   "MYDEF1" ;"MYDEF2")

   set_source_files_properties(${sources} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -fPIC)

   set_property(
   foo.asm
   APPEND
   PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
   "QNXNTO")

   target_include_directories(myLib PRIVATE ../}

The output:

```
/usr/bin/nasm  -DQNXNTO -f elf  -o CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/foo.asm.o -c foo.asm
```